# Pandas - How to sum sentences in a column based on conditions in other columns, and store resulting documents in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a documents list. Each document is combined sentences from the "text" column, when "company" and "date" are the same.

For illustration, I have a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['28/02/2017', 'Apple', "A"], ['28/02/2017', 'Apple', "B"], ['30/03/2017', 'Apple', "C"],
                            ['30/03/2017', 'Apple', "D"],  ['30/02/2017', 'Amazon', "E"]]),
                columns=['date', 'company', 'text'])
```

My desired output is a list with the following sentences:

```py
documents = ["AB", "CD", "E"]
```

So far I thought about creating a "groups" column that would assign a group number to the company&date combinations. Based on the group number, I could sum the text.

I have tried creating a function which would assign those group numbers:

```py
def label_groups(x, count):
    if x['date'] == x['company']:
        return count
    else:
        count = count+1

df['group'] = df.apply(lambda x: label_groups(x, 0), axis=1)
```

But this doesn't work (it returns "None" for every rows).

Perhaps this is an unnecesarrily complicated aproach, and there is a much simpler way of achieving my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) both columns and aggregate with [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
l = df.groupby(['date', 'company'], sort=False).text.agg(''.join).values.tolist()

print(l)
# ['AB', 'E', 'CD']
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Is there a way to also add a column with indexes so that I could identify which documents belongs to which group?

Comment: A column? But you want the result as a list right? How would you want the indices, in another list? @arctic.queenolina

Comment: Updated @arctic.queenolina by specifying sort=False the groups are in the same order. So the nth element in the list is the nth group

Comment: Yes, I do want the results as a list, like you did in the solution. But also, I need a column in the dataframe which, for each row, specifies which index in the document list this row belongs to.  So in the example, it would be a column with values: 0,0,1,1,2  (I'm sorry, I didn't specify it in the question, but I now realise that otherwise I won't be able to analyse the results).

Comment: You can use `df['ix_col'] = df.groupby(['date', 'company'], sort=False).text.ngroup()` @arctic.queenolina